# Radii of touching spheres centered on Pythagorean triple vertices.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, triangles, pythagorean-triples

There are similar questions and answers out there but other *answers* I have seen seem unnecessarily complicated.
I came up with what I think is a simple approach some time ago but I'm now doubting my past reasoning.

Three spheres have centers at the vertices of a Pythagorean triple and they touch at points along the sides of that triangle. How do we find the radii of these spheres?

For the diagram below, is this logic sound? I cannot remember how I arrived at the conclusion in equation (1). Can anyone help reconstruct the logic?
\begin{align*}
R_1+R_2=8\qquad
R_1+R_3&=15\qquad
R_2+R_3=17\\
\\
\implies (R_1+R_3)-(R_1+R_2) &=(15-8)=7\\
&=(R_3-R_2)\tag{1}\\
\implies (R_2+R_3)+(R_3-R_2) &=2R_3= (17+7)=24\tag{2}\\
\implies R_3=\dfrac{24}{2}&=12\tag{3}\\
\implies R_2=(17-12)&=5\tag{4}\\
\implies R_1=(8-5)&=3\tag{5}
\end{align*}
[image]

Comment: It looks like you're simply solving the linear system by clever combination of equations.

Comment: @Blue  Suddenly, I see that I simply collected terms of the first subtraction on the LHS. Thanks.

Comment: Right. Putting the first two steps together, you've effectively added two equations and subtracted the third, doubling one $R_i$ and canceling the others.