# Vertex circle radii of Pythagorean triples

Tags: algebra-precalculus, triangles, pythagorean-triples

@Blue was kind with his comments on a previous question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4730440/radii-of-touching-spheres-centered-on-pythagorean-triple-vertices?noredirect=1#comment10118209_4730440).

I'd now like to share some new relationships I found using algegra and my favorite formula for generating Pythagorean triples. In this example, I'm using
$\,F(n,k)=F(1,1)=(3,4,5),\,\,$ but it works for all such triples. Oddly enough, the radius of the right angle circle is also the inradius of the triangle.

[image]

$\textbf{UPDATE}$

Per comment from @David K, Using Euclid's formula
$\,A=p^2-q^2\quad B=2pq\quad C=p^2+q^2.$
\begin{align*}
r_1&=\dfrac{A+C-B}{2}=\dfrac{(p^2-q^2)+(p^2+q^2)-(2pq)}{2}
=p (p - q)\\
r_2&=\dfrac{A+B-C}{2}=\dfrac{(p^2-q^2)+(2pq)-(p^2+q^2)}{2}
=(p-q)q\\
r_3&=\dfrac{B+C-A}{2}=\dfrac{(2pq)+(p^2+q^2)-(p^2-q^2)}{2}
=(p + q)q
\end{align*}

Comment: So in terms of the triple $(p^2-q^2,2pq,p^2+q^2)$, where $p=2n+k-1$ and $q=k$, you have $r_1=(p-q)^2+(p-q)q=(p-q)p$, $r_2=(p-q)q$, and $r_3=(p-q)q+2q^2=(p+q)q$.

Comment: Exactly the conclusion I reached.